# Is this proof on addition valid

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic

> this proof has to show that adding an even number and an odd number give an odd number. So let $a$ be an even number and $b$ is an odd number $c$ is an even number and $c=b-1$ so:

$$a+b=d$$ substitute $b=c+1$ so, $$a+c+1=d$$ use the fact that $even+even=even$ so $a+c$ is even and $even+1=odd$ so $d$ is odd. Hence $$even+odd=odd$$ Is this proof valid?

Comment: I find it very difficult to read.  I would personally have done this from first principles.  An even number is a number written in the form $2k$ for some integer $k$.  An odd number is a number written in the form $2k+1$ for some integer $k$.  Every integer is exactly one of either odd or even and is never both simultaneously.  So, an even number plus an odd number can be written as $(2k)+(2\ell+1)$ which can be rearranged in a convenient way...

Comment: A specific step in your proof I find troubling is when you claim that $even+1=odd$.  It is not clear why you should know that particular step to be true without knowing the more general $even+odd=odd$ to be true, and it seems like it could be circular.

Comment: I know that even+1=odd because when you count 1 from an even number there is always an odd number that fact was based on logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, well, mostly.   You have shown that $d$ is the addition of $1$ to the sum of two even numbers (from the premises), and claim by some facts that infers that $d$ is an odd number.

Your argument is valid *if* you are given those facts.   Were they provided as part of the problem?   Otherwise you will have to demonstrate them from the definitions of even and odd numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You proof seems unclear, although partially correct. I'll try to propose a more precise version of the same proof.

Suppose that $a$ is even, and $b$ is odd. This means that there exist $k$ and $h$ such that:

$$a = 2k,$$

and

$$b = 2h + 1.$$

Then:

$$d = a + b = 2k + 2h + 1 = 2(k+h) + 1.$$

Since $d$ is expressed as $$d = 2z+ 1,$$

where $z = k+h$, then we can conclude that $d$ is odd.

Comment: This is a `proof-verification` post. Please treat I as such.

Comment: @Shaun I know. I've just tried to transform the proposed proof in a more "understandable" (and maybe more rigorous) one. But the step are the same as the those proposed by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you are trying to prove that $o(dd)+e(ven)=o$ and you use the fact that $e+e=e$ you have a little hole in the logic. This can be easily proven:
$$a+b=2c+2d=2(c+d)=2k$$ hence $e+e=e$

The other part is that $e+1=o$. You should also prove this:

Let $a_n$ be the $n^{th}$ even number: $a_n=2n$ the $(n+1)^{th}$ element is $2(n+1)=2n+2$ hence $a_n<a_n+1<a_{n+1}$ hence $e+1$ is odd.

---

I want to point out that those are just things I think you can improve to make the proof better, you don't have to use them, the original proof is good.